# Javascript replacing image source

Tags: javascript, image, class, attributes, edit

I am trying to change the contents of the src tag within a web page (without changing the HTML/naming structure)

My code looks something like this at the moment:

....

```
<div class="main">
    <button>
        <img src="image/placeHolder.png"/>
        <div>the nothing</div>
    </button>
</div>
```

....

I need to change the src of this img tag
My javascript looks like this at the moment

....

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeSource() {

    var image = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    var source = image.getAttribute("src").replace("placeHolder.png", "01.png");
    image.setAttribute("src", source);
}

changeSource();

</script>
```

....

I have no idea why it isn't working but I'm hoping someone out there does :D

Comment: what are these wings???

Comment: by the way I used the ^ instead of </> because the editor kept turning it into HTML

Comment: 0_0 somehow my wings disappeared

Comment: There is a "Code Sample" button in the editor that you can use to format your code snippets. I updated your question and removed the wings. :)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` returns NodeList, you need to use `querySelector` or just access the first (or any other) element e.g. `image[0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
function changeSource() {
    var image = document.querySelectorAll("img")[0];
    var source = image.src = image.src.replace("placeholder.png","01.png");
}
changeSource();
```

`querySelectorAll` returns an array. I took the first one by doing `[0]`.

But you should use `document.getElementById('id of img here')` to target a specific `<img>`

If you want to target all `<img>` that has `placeholder.png`.

```
function changeSourceAll() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if (images[i].src.indexOf('placeholder.png') !== -1) {
            images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("placeholder.png", "01.png");
        }
    }
}
changeSourceAll();
```

Comment: But the image's src is `image/placeholder.png`, it will be changed so: `01.png`, it should be `image/01.png`

Comment: this answered smacked it, smacked it hard, thanks to everyone :D

Comment: although I do have one more question regards to this answer. how will I be able to apply this same selector and format when the image number [0] is undetermined?

Comment: use `document.getElementById('id of image')`

Comment: I'm unable to use ids because the web page I am editing is set to generate it's own ids through php, so the ids are always randomized as the img elements are invoked. Is there a way to use [0] but to use it as ["any number"] not like that ofcors but in the correct syntax

Comment: do you want to do that for every image?

Comment: yes for every image, it should only effect the sources that will have "placeholder.png" anyway

Comment: so document.querySelectorAll("img")["all?"]

Comment: Not for this project no

Comment: The new version for your solution is working perfectly although I have shortened it slightly to be able to work on multiple images

Comment: function changeSourceAll() {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
 for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
            images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("placeholder01.png", "update01.png");
 for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
     images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("placeholder02.png", "update02.png");
}
changeSourceAll();

Comment: function changeSourceAll() {<br/>
    var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");<br/>
 for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)<br/>
            images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("placeholder01.png", "update01.png");<br/>
 for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)<br/>
     images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("placeholder02.png", "update02.png");<br/>
}
changeSourceAll();

Comment: omg I don't know how to work the formatting in the comments :{

Answer (score 2):

```
function changeSource() {
   var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
   img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('src').replace("placeHolder.png", "image.png"));
}
```

Comment: this is an interesting way to use get/setAttribute that I didn't know about :D I will likely use this, thanks a bunch